# Check AllowOverride value using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is there anyway to use PHP to check the value of `AllowOverride` too see if `.htaccess` will have any effect?

Comment: Do you have http access to the folder you want to test this in?

Comment: I'm trying to test from a php file accessible via http yes. Within the web root. (e.g. `example.com/test.php`)

Answer (score 10):

I am not aware of a clean, direct way to do this.

If you have http access to the folder you want to check this for, you could write something into the .htaccess file that will trigger a certain kind of output.

For example, you could set a header (this has an added dependency on `mod_headers`, though):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set htaccess_works "yes"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

then make a request from PHP, and check the response headers, e.g. using [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)'s `CURLOPT_HEADER`. If they contain the `htaccess_works` header, it works.

Another  method that is terrible but guaranteed to work independently from specific Apache modules is to programmatically write gibberish into the `.htaccess` file, then to make a curl request like above, and to check for a `500` status code. If it throws a 500, the .htaccess file got interpreted. But as said, this is terrible - if possible, go with the headers method instead.

Comment: I did something sort of similar to this.. I was trying to restrict access to certain file types with htaccess (inc, bak, etc). My solution performed a file_get_contents through a http:// wrapper on the restricted files. If I get the content back, I know that the .htaccess file is not taking effect. If I get null returned I know that the server is performing the deny override.

Answer (score 5):

In complement to @Pekka response:

[AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) can be set to **None** or **All**, but as well to a specific list of terms:
**AuthConfig**, **FileInfo**, **Indexes**, **Limit**, **Options**. So you could be allowed to use a Header instruction but not Deny, for example.

So a way to test the real value of AllowOverride is to add this to your .htaccess:

```
#AuthConfig
AuthName "Secret"
#FileInfo
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
#Indexes
DefaultIcon /icon/unknown.xbm 
#Limit
Allow From All
#Options
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Then if you have an 500 error comment lines to detect which words (sections) are forbidden. You'll get an error 500 until you remove every forbidden instruction. When you'll know the allowed sections you'll have to check the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for the complete list of allowed instructions.

If you do not have any error you have AllowOverride None or All. Then alter the Deny/Allow to:

```
Deny From All
```

If you have the 403 result it's a AllowOverride All.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way

Add: show-error in the first line on your page an load domain via browser to trigger a 50x error

> Another method that is terrible but guaranteed to work independently
>   from specific Apache modules is to programmatically write gibberish
>   into the .htaccess file, then to make a curl request like above, and
>   to check for a 500 status code. If it throws a 500, the .htaccess file
>   got interpreted. But as said, this is terrible - if possible, go with
>   the headers method instead.