# htaccess Login works on one site but not the other

Tags: .htaccess, authentication

I'm working on providing a simple username/password gate for a client's website.  I'm using a simple combo of htaccess and htpasswd files to accomplish this.

For right now, I'm only using dummy names and passwords, so, I feel comfortable posting those here.

Login 1: sean
PW 1: CreAgent

Login 2: sally
PW 2: pass

PWs were encrypted using this site (www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/).

As you can see, it all works fine [at this location](http://www.nintemple.com/login/).

Here is the code in the .htaccess file at that location:

```
AuthName "Employees Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/content/n/i/n/nintemple1/html/login/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

And here is the htpasswd file...

```
sean:[encrypted password - not sure if I should post this!]
sally:[encrypted password - not sure if I should post this!]
```

Now, that webspace above is my own.  So, then I tried to set things up [on the client's space](http://www.aimcil.com/JAL/).  As you can see from that link, it just keeps treating the login as incorrect (offering new attempts) until you hit cancel and then it returns a 401 error.  Everything is identical except that I changed the path to the new htpasswd file.  So, the new htaccess file is like so...

```
AuthName "AIM Employees Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/aimcilco/public_html/JAL/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

I know it's possible that the client's space might be configured differently.  But, the space where their files are hosted does not have a phone # to contact with questions and I posted on their forum weeks ago with no reply. So, I can't just ask the people who run the server.  I do see other htaccess files in their space though, so, I imagine things are at least somewhat configured to handle htaccess.

I will admit that I am out of my depth here.  I felt confident setting this up (since I got it working on my own space), but, I don't know enough about how these things work to properly trouble shoot this issue. =\

Thanks in advance and let me know if there is any more info you need from me to best solve this problem!

Comment: What version of Apache is being used? Does the client server have [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) set?

Comment: Again, I'm out of my depth. How can I check those things if I can't get in touch with the people who own/operate said server?

Comment: Check `AllowOverride` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137139/1626250). And you can check the Apache version by creating a PHP file containing only `<?php phpinfo();`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. Here is the only line in the output that mentioned Apache: 

`Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4`

Does that tell us anything valuable?  If you needed other info, I could link to the test PHP file's URL, but, I'm not sure if there is any sensitive information in that output.

I don't know how to do that AllowOverride test, but, I'm looking up some info on PHP and I'll try to figure that out on my own if I can.

Thank you for working with me on this!